# R - Too many lines returned by a merge

Tags: r, merge

When I perform the following instruction:

I have 55208 rows in table and I want the same number of row in table2. But that's not the case. I used this instruction :

```
table2 = merge(table,
          base.temperature,
          by.x=c("date.de.cotation","depot"),
          by.y=c("date","depot"),
          all.x=T)
```

table has 55208 rows
and table2 has 57462 rows

How is it possible to return more rows than table with the condition : all.x=T ?

Comment: Please provide `dput(table)` and `dput(base.temperature)`

Comment: My datas are confidentials

Comment: that means that you had duplicates in `base.temperature` table

Comment: That's it, thank you !